# In Tensorflow, how can I access my model's weights when computing loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm implementing a model described in a research paper (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9897541 for those with access to IEEEExplore, although not necessary to understand this question) which proposes a loss function.

This **loss function** is computed in part from the **weights matrix** from one of the layers in the model (a fully-connected layer which is a Keras Dense layer object in my code).

I've got a class subclassed from `Keras.Model` which has a custom implementation of `train_step()`.

In the `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:` block, I calculate the loss, which involves calling `M = self.fc_layer.get_weights()[0]`, which returns a NumPy array. As this datatype is not a Tensorflow datatype, it appears that it is unable to associate the loss generated on the gradient tape with the trainable weights, as I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['conv1_conv/kernel:0', 'conv1_conv/bias:0', 'conv1_bn/gamma:0', 'conv1_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block1_1_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block1_1_conv/bias:0', 'conv2_block1_1_bn/gamma:0', 'conv2_block1_1_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block1_2_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block1_2_conv/bias:0', 'conv2_block1_2_bn/gamma:0', 'conv2_block1_2_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block1_0_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block1_0_conv/bias:0', 'conv2_block1_3_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block1_3_conv/bias:0', 'conv2_block1_0_bn/gamma:0', 'conv2_block1_0_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block1_3_bn/gamma:0', 'conv2_block1_3_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block2_1_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block2_1_conv/bias:0', 'conv2_block2_1_bn/gamma:0', 'conv2_block2_1_bn/beta:0', 'conv2_block2_2_conv/kernel:0', 'conv2_block2_2_conv/bias:0', 
etc.
```

If I'm correct in thinking that this is the problem, how could I access the weights of `self.fc_layer` without breaking away from the requirements of the Tensorflow graph? I've got Eager Execution enabled just to get this far, which I'm assuming is a clear indicator that my current code is not graph-compatible for that reason.

*Extra information if you're interested:
The reason the weights are needed in the loss function is because one row of the weights matrix represents a class centre, from which cosine similarity between that and the centre is computed, to maximise inter-class difference in an embedding generated for a vehicle re-identification task.*

Comment: Do not describe your code, include the code directly in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest building your own fully connected layer. A basic dense layer, taking into account the new class viewpoint $$M \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times C\times V}$$, is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class DenseCustom(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self,C,V,activation=None,activity_regularizer=None,kernel_initializer="GlorotUniform",trainable=True,seed=None,**kwargs):
        # pylint: enable=g-doc-args
        super(DenseCustom, self).__init__(
                activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
                **kwargs)

        self.C=C
        self.V=V
        self.activation_fn=activation
        if(self.activation_fn is None):
            self.activation_fn="linear"
        self.kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer
        self.trainable=trainable
        self.seed = seed

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape)==2#only for batch, features rank
        
        last_dim=input_shape[-1]

        input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape)

        kernel_initializer=self.kernel_initializer

        if(type(kernel_initializer) is str):
            kernel_initializer=getattr(tf.keras.initializers, kernel_initializer)()

        self.kernel = self.add_weight('kernel',shape=[self.C, self.V, last_dim],initializer=kernel_initializer,dtype=tf.float32,trainable=self.trainable)

        self.built = True
```

You do not need to access the weights of the network at learning time in the loss. You only need to make the output of the network the necessary to plug in the loss. The output should be $$\phi=\frac{M\cdot x_i}{||M||\cdot ||x_i||}$$. The call function would take the form:

```
    @tf.function
    def call(self, X):
        
        M=self.kernel

        norm_M=tf.expand_dims(tf.norm(M, ord=2,axis=2), axis=-1)
        norm_X=tf.norm(X, ord=2)

        #L_R reunion loss
        self.add_loss(lambda : tf.reduce_sum((-2/(self.V*(self.V-1)))*tf.einsum("CVD, CVD-> D", M/norm_M, M/norm_M)) )

        return tf.einsum("BD,CVD->BCV",X/norm_X, M/norm_M,)
```

Now you can implement directly the loss of equation (3), being the output of this network $$\phi$$.

If you execute this code you get a tensor with the desired shape:

```
C=5
V=7

view_layer=DenseCustom(C,V)

x = tf.ones((10,4))

view_layer(x).shape
```

Output:
`TensorShape([10, 5, 7])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. Just got a query about it, when you've calculated `norm_M=tf.norm(M, ord=2,axis=[0,1]`, would this not be a different sort of normalisation than is needed for this? From my limited understanding, this would be a matrix normalisation, which I think is a different sort of operation to a vector normalisation? So would it not have to be `norm_M = tf.norm(M, ord=2, axis=2)`, meaning that the einsum operations would also have to be different? Apologies if I'm reading the research paper incorrectly on this point, maths is not a strength of mine.

Comment: @magmacollaris yes, I think you're correct. It makes sense to be on the $$d$$ dimension of $$M \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times C\times V}$$. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @magmacollaris I don't see why the einsum would have to be different. The vectors that enter the einsum are normalized, so it represents the cosine.